# Find text in source code of page and create hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, search

I need to use JavaScript to search the source code of the current page for a string, e.g `data-userId="2008"`, then extracts the id number (2008 in this case) and creates a hyperlink to include it, e.g. `http://www.google.com?2008`.

I've been attempting to use indexOf and document.documentElement.innerHTML approaches but not getting anywhere. I've got closer with the help of [this post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?16108-Find-text-string-in-a-web-page-s-html-source-code) but no success yet.

Here's what i have so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getVals() {
    code = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
    results = code.match(/data-userId=(\d*)&/g);
    for (i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
        value = results[i].match(/data-userId=(\d*)&/);
    }
}
onload = getVals;
document.write(code);
    </script>
```

Due to restrictions on our network the solution needs to be JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the getAttribute() method of the Element object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp.

I'm not sure why exactly you'd query the html element and then look at innerHTML. Do you not know which tags/selectors will contain the data attribute you're looking for? If you don't know which selectors you're looking for you can use a recursive function like this to walk the DOM and store the values in a data structure of your choice - I'll use an array of objects in this example (not sure how you need this data formatted).

Also, I'm not sure how you're choosing to visit these pages, but the below code could be easily modified to create hyperlinks when/if the attributes you're looking for are found.

```
var storeElements = [];

function walkTheDOM(node){
    if(node.getAttribute('data-userId') !== null){
        storeElements.push({"element": node, "attrValue": node.getAttribute('data-userId'});
    }

    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node){
        walkTheDOM(node);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function like this:

```
walkTheDOM(document.querySelectorAll('html')[0]);
```

If this isn't what you're looking for let me know and I can change my answer. For those of you who've read Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts" this function may look very familiar :).

Comment: wow! instead of your homebrew DOM walker, why don't you use the official [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) ?

Comment: I actually haven't used that before - looks interesting. I checked it out briefly and it might just be easier to use what I wrote in my answer rather than figuring out that object. If there's an easier solution using TreeWalker you should post an answer. I'd be interested to see how you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, the reason i'm using the HTML element is i'm a total noob and don't know any better! I'm hoping your DOM method above will work - how would I show the userID that's been found on screen, through document.write?

Comment: So I'm not sure exactly how your process transpires, but I'll give it a go. It sounds like you have a little window that's showing a user the progress of querying the DOM. It could say something like "1 user IDs found" where 1 is displayed on the screen using a counter variable. So, inside of the if statement where you would check for "if attribute is found" you could add counter ++ which would show the user that an additional element has been found. Hope that helps.